# jQuery click doesn't work when included in a separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am a beginner learning jQuery and web development, so this may be a dumb question, but I cannot find an answer to this on Google (probably I'm not searching for the right keywords). I have a simple HTML file (say, 'test.html' that loads jQuery, an external javascript file (say, 'test.js') that I wrote, and have a button in it. For example,

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="" id="summary_employee">Search by Name</a></li>
              </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summary_employee').click(function (event) {
        dataString = $("#summary_employee").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>hodm_summary/search_by_employee",
            data:dataString,

            success:function (data) {
                $('#search').html(data);
            }

        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But when I click on the button, it doesn't work. However, when I put what's in 'test.js' code in 'test.html' then it work.

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Put `<script src="scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` before close of `body`

Comment: Have you checked the console on click?

Comment: Are you putting the correct file? Any errors in console?

Comment: Check that 'src="scripts/test.js"' is this the correct link to include the js file.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the click is bind before the HTML tags is loaded in the DOM. Please put your test js file after the dom loaded and then your click binds properly.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="" id="summary_employee">Search by Name</a></li>
              </ul>
      <script src="scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

or else use Event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '#summary_employee', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     //Paste your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your test.js

```
function getBaseUrl() {
    pathArray = location.href.split( '/' );
    protocol = pathArray[0];
    host = pathArray[2];
    return protocol + '//' + host;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summary_employee').click(function (event) {
        dataString = $("#summary_employee").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: getBaseUrl() + "/hodm_summary/search_by_employee",
            data:dataString,

            success:function (data) {
                $('#search').html(data);
            }

        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You can't use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` in your test.js file because it's a PHP script.